# Should I flag answers where people are just selling products?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, spam, self-promotion

I'm new to C# and thus I have been really hammering the C# tag lately. In my ventures, I keep landing on answers like this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2683152/562566
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26119363/562566
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541555/562566
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4198179/562566
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5231309/562566
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12258636/562566
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21180791/562566
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17363725/562566
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2588217/562566

and so on and so forth. I could paste probably a hundred more, but I don't wanna bore people too much. I've tried to report some of these, the flags are still listed as "active" after almost a week. Not sure what's up there.

As you can see, a large percent of these answers offer absolutely nothing of value to the site, just a backlink to a commercial product. In some cases, the answers are completely off-topic, one of the links someone asks for an open source library, the answer given is "buy our 20 thousand dollar security toolbox" (paraphrase).

I understand that, with some disclosure, some advertisement is acceptable so long as the answer is contributing something of value and is on-topic. But, where is the limit? Should I bother flagging stuff like this?

My post doesn't seem to be drawing any official response so, I'm tagging this as a feature request and asking that clear rules be defined, measurable, well defined rules against this sort of stuff. This stuff is pollution in our community and only serves to drive users away from the site. While there are situations where a commercial product might be the only feasible solution to a problem, spamming links to them (or to any external, boxed solution for that matter) is really against the spirit of the network: **education**.

Comment: Look at the user's answer history. If they have an obvious pattern of always linking to their products/services, then just flag one of their answers as other, and write a detailed description of the issue including links to the answers you've found. And a mod will handle from there.

Comment: To look for this things, I search for `user:USER-ID url:PRODUCT-URL`, then flag one post informing of everything if the findings ring some bell.

Comment: @cVplZ I thought so too, but like I say in my question, I've done this (more than once) and the flags go un-answered. They're just left open. So hopefully I can get some official input as to what's going on, if I'm wasting my time or if this has somehow slipped under the radar.

Comment: It's pretty frustrating. Just for giggles, take up the task of learning anything to do with cryptography in C#. Your googling will 9/10 times bring you back to an answer where this user specifically is selling a product.

Comment: For what it's worth there are almost 1300 custom flags pending right now they do get processed, but a lot of them take quite a bit of time to process.

Comment: Also for what it's worth, that particular individual has been flagged before for self-promotion. (I don't have links, but moderators will be able to access them.)

Comment: @Flexo my comment isn't meant to put down to call to account moderators or anything. I'm just bringing this issue to light because honestly, the C# tag in particular is overrun with this kind of stuff. I'm finding more useful information by leaving SO in my search, which we can all agree isn't good.

Comment: I'm also bringing it up to get clarification as to what is too much. Perhaps I should tag this as a feature request, asking someone to break out the gavel and make an official ruling by clearly defining what is useful and what is just spam?

Comment: He is one of two well-known spammers at SO, featured many times in meta posts.  The moderators appear to have a hard time dealing with them, they play it well by also sometimes posting useful answers.  The only really positive thing to say about it is that they've toned down the spam over the years.  Nothing much that SO-users can do about it but the obvious approach, downvote a useless answer.

Comment: Point taken about disclosure. There doesn't seem to be any in the first answer you referenced http://stackoverflow.com/a/2683152/397817

Comment: @HansPassant I've downvoted, but then I risk getting in trouble myself. I've had my voting history flagged for this and then mods come along, give me crap and reverse the votes. Even that aside, even with my almost 7K rep, I think I'd vote myself out of the ability to comment if I downvoted all these.

Comment: Well, downvote a post when you happen to run into one of them.  Serial downvoting is considered iffy and triggers a rule that cancels them.  Fairly doubtful that you got crap from a moderator about downvoting Mayevski's posts btw, they ought to know him well enough.  And no, canceled downvotes do not remove any rights.

Comment: A quick Google search showed a considerable amount of posts from this individual referencing that product. Most seem to be just a link to the Eldos page and basic description of how it works - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3882683/845568 for example.

Comment: As far as an official response goes I'm not sure what would be added over: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers. My personal view though: if people are seeing any kind of answers that aren't helpful why are they scored 0, irrespective of which side of the spam line they fall? Vote vote vote!

Comment: So I guess we're all idiots now: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26119363/4

Comment: Indeed. I hope one day I can be the CEO of a company and have to drum up business by spamming links and insulting people on SO.

Comment: @HansPassant curious how the mods have a hard time with him. Can't mods not ban a user if they fail to comply after a request? Seems that even with a high rep self promotion shouldn't be allowed. Otherwise SO will just become some awful sponsored version of itself

Comment: @Parker I don't know, but I'd think they have a hard time with him since he actually most of the time complies. If you look at the answers linked IMO most are partly related, on-topic answers, but they also include advertising to their product. It's a thin line. If it were just spam links, it would be easier to deal with.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: He's expressing a viewpoint that people who don't bother to read the official guideline on self-promotion, or actively go against it, and vote to close and delete his posts that comply with the guidelines, are idiots.  I wouldn't have said it that way, but I do agree that Technik and others need to stop complaining about posts that follow the rules.  That said, "our product" is NEVER an entire answer to any question.  If "our product does that" is a complete on-topic answer to a question, then **there's a problem with the question**.  Qs asking for tools need deletion.

Comment: A focused [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=secureblackbox&rct=j#q=%22secureblackbox%22+site:stackoverflow.com) shows the product mentioned in 841 times. A focused [search on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=secureblackbox+user%3A47961+is%3Aanswer) shows this individual has mentioned it in 212 answers. That's more than 15% of this guys answers for a single product. Pretty excessive IMHO.

Comment: Well @BenVoigt, I've been combing SO figuring out how to make a MITM proxy in C# and I can tell you that almost every answer related to TLS, certificate generation, packet diversion in the context of TLS, etc, comes back to "buy my product". Yes, his product can do what I'd like, but frankly I don't come here to go shopping, I come here to educate and be educated. So I think as a contributing member, I have a right to complain. All of his rep was gained from just a handful of very highly upvoted answers. The rest basically have no votes, because they are spam.

Comment: @BenVoigt I get what you're saying, the question itself is also in the wrong and we can't necessarily blame only the person posting the spam messages. But I respectfully disagree, since the questions were most likely formatted incorrectly due to ignorance, while the spam was craftily, deliberately generated.

Comment: @Ben: Are you referring to [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26119363/revisions)? Do you think my edit shouldn't have happened? Please let me know. I am open to advice.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire: You should be getting valuable information on how to do it by hand, and if you're getting an additional message of "But you can bypass a LOT of work by using our commercial product", that's fine.  Such information is valuable to readers.  But it does need to be a side message, not replace actually answering the question.  The bad questions are ones that don't ask for the technical information, they just ask for a product recommendation.  In those cases cleaning up the recommendation-only answer is pointless... it complies with policy.  But it should die with the off-topic Q.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I don't think you should have removed that footnote.  It was a footnote, not the main thrust of the answer, and the main answer seems informative.  And it even mentions a second product, which appears to be a competing solution.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: From another perspective, it means that for each answer that advances his sales, he's been willing to expend effort giving technical answers to 6+ questions (five unrelated to his product).  While we can wish for a higher ratio, it's also true that experts gain expertise through practice, and so the answers they can give with confidence are related in some way to their work.  Also, if we kill off the tool recommendation questions, his ratio will improve.

Comment: @Ben: okay. Did a roll back.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an official guideline on self-promotion in the [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/245360).

The general consensus seems to consist of two necessary items:

1. You have to be fair and square you have any interest in the tool you recommend. If you are promoting your own product, just tell you do.
2. Just as important, be on-topic. If the tool is useful for the question asked, it's okay. You shouldn't just post distant related content.

That said, there isn't one answer to the question you asked. *We*, as a community, have to review each and every post on its usefulness. If it is useful, keep it, if useless downvote and flag as spam.

Giving the number of posts this user made self-promoting, I do understand this might need more attention then just handling it per post, so it is good you came here so the community can help in this and bring it to the attention of the moderators.

This line from the faq says a lot:

> Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product, you're clearly here for the wrong reasons.

What percentage is reasonable has to be decided by the moderators handling this. As calculated by  [Captain Obvlious](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275289/should-i-flag-answers-where-people-are-just-selling-products#comment110391_275289) the ratio is 14%. In my opinion, this behavior is spam.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The part about "huge percentage of answers" mentioning your product starts to make this a little clearer. But, based on the first two points, he's not really in the wrong. I think that's what I'm addressing. If you look at his answers for example, a lot of them do give good information. But the information, the answers are crafted to leave you hanging still, and of course pointing back to the product.

Comment: Even if it wasn't his own product. I could sit here all day linking people to external libs, commercial or not, that will just do what they want. But again I think this is really against the spirit of the community, education and open access to that education. If we're just linking to stuff off site, boxed solutions, we're not teaching anyone anything. We're basically becoming one of those scraping sites we all hate, coming up in google yet linking to basically the google result after us.

Comment: So those answers are crafted to fit the product. Then it is spam, but written by a very smart user.

Comment: That is one of the reason recommendation questions are off-topic now. That focuses on the solution instead of the tool.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire Thats also why link-only answers aren't allowed. We are *not* a scraping site.

Comment: There's a third point -- **The answer must offer useful on-topic technical information in addition to a product link**.  That's the one many of the linked answers fall afoul of... but generally because the question itself is off-topic, asking for a tool.  If "our product does that" is a complete answer, then the question is bad.

Comment: I agree that this is spam, and strongly agree that less that 15% of your posts should be self-promotional. If we were to all monetize our SO activity (even 15% of it), this would be a very different place indeed. The fact that we *don't* should not create ripe, low-hanging fruit for a select few that do.